# Is code with try-catch still slow when nothing is thrown

Tags: c++, performance, exception, try-catch

In is well known fact that exceptions are good feature but they are slow. Therefore, it is a good practice to use return flags. Now what if I use return flags, but just in case I wrap my code in try-catch, to be 100% sure that it will work disregarding on exceptional situations. I mean that my code will work mainly on flags, not based on exception handling. Now is this a good practice? Is it sill slow?

Comment: It can still impose *some* overhead, but at least in my testing with current compilers the overhead from code using exceptions is *extremely* minimal as long as no exception is actually thrown.

Comment: Why would you complicate things?  If you don't need the speed yet, than you are wasting your time on dangerous *premature optimization*.

Comment: Completely agree, but want to know just for good practice.

Comment: It is a well known fact that sentences beginning with "it is a well known fact" rarely are true. (This one *was* kind of true in the early nineties, but many things that were true then aren't any more). Unless you're doing something where performance is *really* critical like, say, the next AAA blockbuster video game or high frequency trading, they're usually not worth worrying about.

Comment: Exception handling would be cleaner than "excretion handling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that across a wide range of compilers, languages and technologies, the performance cost of a `try-catch` (or similar) when no exeception occurs is minimal and should be disregarded.

The reason is that (in general) all a `try` really does is mark the stack in a particular way, and that's a cheap operation. When an exception is raised is when the work is done. Then the system has to scan the stack looking for `catch` blocks and that can be expensive.

This also applies to constructs like `try-catch-finally` (in languages that have it). The `finally` block is simply executed by a normal transfer of control.

This is a rather generic answer and specific compilers may behave differently but the principle remains: `try` is cheap and raising exceptions is expensive. Feel free to use `try` blocks whenever your design needs it without fear of performance consequences.